# JQGrid inlineNav AddParams Uses Properties From EditParams

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I want to use `JQGrid inlinenav` "`Add`" and "`Edit`" functionalities. Edit functionality works without problem with this code but the problem is that add uses the properties from editParams. When I click save button in `add mode` it goes to the `url` which `editParams` uses. Did I made mistake somewhere or miss something ?

```
             navigation: {
                parameters : {
                    edit: true,
                    editicon: "ui-icon-pencil",
                    add: true,
                    addicon: "ui-icon-plus",
                    save: true,
                    saveicon: "ui-icon-disk",
                    cancel: true,
                    cancelicon: "ui-icon-cancel",
                    editParams: {
                        keys: true,
                        oneditfunc: function (id) { eRowId = id; },
                        onEnterfunc: function () { return editOnEnter(); },
                        successfunc: function (r) { return saveRow(r); },
                        url: ncb.NCB + "/Home/EditBillingTransaction",
                        extraparam: {},
                        aftersavefunc: null,
                        errorfunc: null,
                        afterrestorefunc: null,
                        restoreAfterError: false,
                        mtype: "POST"
                    },
                    addParams: {
                        addRowParams: {
                            keys: true,
                            extraparam: {},
                            successfunc: function () { alert('success'); },
                            url: ncb.NCB + "/Home/AddBillingTransaction",
                            mtype: "POST"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }



jQuery(obj.grid).jqGrid('inlineNav', obj.pager, navigation.parameters);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please include information about the version and the fork of jqGrid which you use in all your question.**

I suppose that you use some old version of jqGrid. **The problem, which you described is the old bug, which is fixed already.** I recommend you to use the current version (4.11.1) of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). It's the fork, which I develop after changing the license agreements of jqGrid and renaming it to commercial product [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) (see [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)). I provide free jqGrid under old MIT/GPLv2 license. If you do will find some bug in free jqGrid I can easy fix it.

By the way I implemented simplified form of parameters used by internal jqGrid methods, like the inline editing methods. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods). The usage of `inlineEditing` option will simplify your code. One more feature of free jqGrid: one can specify `url` as callback function. It allows to build different URLs for Add and Edit in very simple way:

```js
inlineEditing: {
    keys: true,
    ... // other options of inline editing
    url: function (id, editOrAdd) {
        return ncb.NCB +
            (editOrAdd === "edit" ?
                "/Home/EditBillingTransaction" :
                "/Home/AddBillingTransaction");
    }
}
```

I remind that the above option `inlineEditing` is the option of jqGrid (not the option of `navGrid`).

Comment: I am using license jqGrid  4.4.3. Is it old ?

Comment: @TheChampp: It's clear that 4.4.3 is older as 4.11.1. jqGrid 4.4.3 was published Jan 23, 2013 (almost 3 years ago). The simplest way to try free jqGrid is to change URLs to jqGrid files to the URLs described in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). I tried to hold the compatibility with old versions. Thus the versions numbers which I used was 4.x.y. Look at [the simple demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/navButtons1-fa4-.htm) which uses `keys: true` inside of `inlineEditing`.